# post() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) django

Tags: python, django

I've been coding this, so i wanted to create like a forum, and this is the comments part, if you guys can help me i will be really thankfull.

> views.py

```
class createComment(View):
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = "createComment.html"

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

    def post(request):
        try:
            if request.method == "POST":
                form = createComment()
                if form.is_valid():
                    obj = form.save(commit=False)
                    obj.user_comment = request.user
                    obj.body_comment = request.POST["body_comment"]
                    obj.post_comment = request.POST[id]
                    obj.status_comment = False
                    obj.save()
                    return redirect('/')
            else:
                form = createComment()
        except Exception, e:
            return render_to_response("errorTemplate.html", {"message" : e.message})

        return redirect('/')
```

> models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user_comment = models.ForeignKey("auth.User")
    body_comment = models.TextField()
    timestamp_comment = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    post_comment = models.ForeignKey("Post", null=True)
    status_comment = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user_comment)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title_comment
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def get(self, request):
    ...

def post(request):
    ...
```

You forgot the `self` argument.

Comment: If i add **self** as an argument, sends me this error 'createComment' object has no attribute 'is_valid'

Comment: Well that's a new problem within your `post` method, but definitely progress.  `form = createComment()` doesn't look right since that's a `View` not a form.

Comment: I have the same problem with FormView, and if you are talking about function-based views idk what else should i do now

Comment: A FormView is still a view and not a form. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview

Comment: Thank you for your patience